# Functions splitting effect on running time

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I am writing a DSP code in C (windows environment). The code should be modified, by another engineer, to run on Cortex-M4. This engineer claims that, for reduction of running time, many of the functions that I have implemented should be united into one function. I prefer to avoid it keeping clarity and testing.

Does his claim make sense? If it is, where I can read about it. Otherwise, can I show that he is wrong without a comparison of running time?

Comment: Ask him to show you the particular bottle-neck he has in mind. Is the performance poor? The onus is on him, the complainer, to show that, and not just "I don't like your coding style."

Answer (score 4):

> Does his claim make sense?

Depends on context. Modern compilers are perfectly able to inline function calls, but that usually means that those functions must be placed in the same translation unit (essentially the same .c file).

If your functions are in the same .c file then their claim is wrong, if you have the functions scattered across multiple files, then their claim is likely correct.

> If it is, where I can read about it.

*Function inlining* has been around for some 30 years. C even added an `inline` keyword for it in year 1999 (C++ had one earlier still), though during the 2000s compilers turned smarter than programmers in terms of determining when and what to inline. Nowadays when using modern compilers, `inline` is mostly considered obsolete.

> Otherwise, can I show that he is wrong without a comparison of running time?

By disassembling the optimized code and see if there are any function calls or not. Still, function calls are relatively cheap on Cortex M (unless there's a ton of different parameters), so doing manual optimization to remove them would be very tiny optimization.

Comment: Also notably, someone who isn't even aware of such basic optimizations such as function inlining probably shouldn't be writing code for DSPs, let alone tinker around with manual optimizations for a specific target... This is somewhere between beginner-to-intermediate level stuff. I'd expect someone writing code for DSPs in C to be a C expert or at least a veteran with some 5 to 10 years of experience.

Comment: exactly. I consider myself a 35 year C veteran, but I never touched a DSP. I would never make such a claim, at least not without measurement. Inlining the hotspots will probably suffice (given you *know* the hotspots)

Comment: @wildplasser My point is rather that I wouldn't expect a discussion about what function inlining is or if it exists between people tasked to write code for such systems. There's always the "been living underneath a rock since K&R" variety who doesn't know about inlining, and there's of course the rookie fresh out of school variety from don't know much about anything. They tend to be incompetent in very different ways, though the rookie you can at least teach.

Comment: Most modern compilers have some form of link-time optimizer which can inline across translation units too. (-flto for Clang and GCC, for example).

Comment: @solidpixel Yeah or you could simply dump the function as `static inline` in a header file. Which is very ugly but generally portable.

Answer (score 2):

As always there's a choice between code size and execution speed.

If you wish to remove the stack overhead of calling a new function but wish to keep your code modular then consider using the `inline` function attribute suitable for your compiler e.g.

```
static inline  void com_ClearMessageBuffer(uint8_t* pBuffer, uint32_t length)
{
    NRF_LOG_DEBUG("com_ClearMessageBuffer");
    memset(pBuffer, 0, length);
}
```

Then at compile time your inline function code will be inserted into the code flow wherever it is called.

This will speed execution, but when called multiple times increase the code size.